# What are optimality conditions?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control

My question is rather general and in advance I appologize for not being precise enough, which is very likely. It concerns the matter: what do people understand by optimality conditions?

Suppose we have a problem: Find $u^*\in F$ such that 
$$\inf_{u\in F} J(u) = u^*.$$
Also, let $u^*$ be the solution of this problem ($J$ is some energy functional assoiciated with some system of differential equations or differential inequality).

What do we have to do to obtain optimality conditions - what are the? To make myself clear, if we want to solve an equation we look for the solution - what do we have to do find optimality condidtions? Is there any definition (or intuition) of the term "optimality conditions"?

**Edit.** Propably $\frac{\partial J}{\partial u}(u^*)=0$ (Gateaux derivative) is not enough?

Comment: "Optimality condition" is simply a general term for conditions on the optimization variable $u$ which are necessary or sufficient for it to be an optimal point for the original problem (and which are easier to check than proving $J(u)\le J(v)$ for all $v\in F$). For example, if you want to minimize a twice-differentiable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, "$f'(x)=0$" is a necessary but not sufficient optimality condition; "$f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)>0$" is a sufficient but not necessary optimality condition.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial u}(u^*)(u-u^*)\ge 0 $$
for all $u\in F$.

Comment: This condition is only necessary for optimality if the set $F$ is convex!